# Dynamic Tables?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I have a database that has different grades per course (i.e. three homeworks for Course 1, two homeworks for Course 2, ... ,Course N with M homeworks). How should I handle this as far as database design goes?

```
CourseID HW1  HW2 HW3
    1    100  99  100
    2    100  75  NULL
```

**EDIT**
I guess I need to rephrase my question.  As of right now, I have two tables, Course and Homework.  Homework points to Course through a foreign key.  My question is how do I know how many homeworks will be available for each class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decompose the table into three different tables. One holds the courses, the second holds the homeworks, and the third connects them and stores the result.

Course:

```
CourseID CourseName
1        Foo
```

Homework:

```
HomeworkID HomeworkName HomeworkDescription
HW1        Bar          ...
```

Result:

```
CourseID HomeworkID Result
1        HW1        100
```

Comment: Downvoted because the model suggested has Homework and Course as independent entities - any Homework can apply to any Course.  As Homework is functionally dependent on Course, `CourseID` should be a foreign key column in `Homework` referencing the `Course` table, and the third table should be eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a good design.  It's an antipattern that I [called](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) *Metadata Tribbles*.  You have to keep adding new columns for each homework, and they propagate out of control.

It's an example of *repeating groups*, which violates the [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of relational database design.

Instead, you should create one table for `Courses`, and another table for `Homeworks`.  Each row in Homeworks references a parent row in Courses.

> My question is how do I know how many homeworks will be available for each class?

You'd add rows for each homework, then you can count them as follows:

```
SELECT CourseId, COUNT(*) AS Num_HW_Per_Course
FROM Homeworks
GROUP BY CourseId
```

Of course this only counts the homeworks *after* you have populated the table with rows.  So you (or the course designers) need to do that.